# i am trying to build a parser for mini java where i am getting shift/reduce conflicts in the expression grammar part.I can't resolve this conflict

Tags: parsing, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

this is part of y.ouput file

state 65

15 Expression: Expression . "&&" Expression

16           | Expression . "<" Expression

17           | Expression . "+" Expression

18           | Expression . "-" Expression

19           | Expression . "*" Expression

20           | Expression . "[" Expression "]"

21           | Expression . "." "length"

22           | Expression . "." Identifier "(" Expression "," Expression ")"

25           | "!" Expression .

```
"["  shift, and go to state 67
"<"  shift, and go to state 69
"+"  shift, and go to state 70
"-"  shift, and go to state 71
"*"  shift, and go to state 72
"."  shift, and go to state 73

"["       [reduce using rule 25 (Expression)]
"<"       [reduce using rule 25 (Expression)]
"+"       [reduce using rule 25 (Expression)]
"-"       [reduce using rule 25 (Expression)]
"*"       [reduce using rule 25 (Expression)]
"."       [reduce using rule 25 (Expression)]
$default  reduce using rule 25 (Expression)
```

this is how the precedence of operators is set

```
%left "&&"

%left '<'

%left '-' '+' 

%left '*'

%right '!'

%left '.'

%left '(' ')'

%left '[' ']'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bison, there is a difference between `"x"` and `'x'`; they are not the same token. So, assuming you are using bison, your precedence declarations don't refer to the terminals in the productions.

Bison also allows `%token` definitions of the following form:

```
%token name quoted-string ...
```

For example (a short excerpt from bison's own grammar file):

```
%token
  PERCENT_CODE            "%code"
  PERCENT_DEBUG           "%debug"
  PERCENT_DEFAULT_PREC    "%default-prec"
  PERCENT_DEFINE          "%define"
  PERCENT_DEFINES         "%defines"
  PERCENT_ERROR_VERBOSE   "%error-verbose"
```

Once the symbols have been aliased, they can be used interchangeably in the grammar, making it possible to use the double-quoted string in productions; some people find such grammars easier to read. However, there is no mechanism to ensure that the lexer produces the correct token number for a double-quoted string since it only has access to the token names.

The "original" yacc, at least in the current ["byacc" version](http://invisible-island.net/byacc/) maintained by Thomas Dickey, allows both single- and double-quoted token names, but does not distinguish between them; both `"+"` and `'+'` are mapped to token number 43 ('+'). It also does not provide any easy way to alias token names, so the double-quoted multi-character strings are not particularly easy to use in a reliable way.

Comment: Generally you NEVER want to use `"`-quoted tokens, as there is no easy way to get your lexer to return them properly to your parser.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: unless you alias them to a token name (`%token AND_TOKEN "&&"`), which arguably makes the grammar more readable.

Comment: @rici: that doesn't alias them -- it just declares two tokens.  In order to alias them, you need to alias them explicitly to the same fixed integer:  `%token AND_TOKEN "&&" 512`, which can be done but is error prone.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Token-Decl.html#Token-Decl "Once you equate the literal string and the token name, you can use them interchangeably in further declarations or the grammar rules." (By the way, it would be `%token AND_TOKEN 512 "&&"`, but that usage is indeed error-prone.)

Comment: @rici: interesting -- that would seem to be a bison extension -- 'normal' yacc doesn't work that way.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I tried to summarize comments in answer, in case it becomes useful to someone else.